# Same Bundle Hash but currentIndex is always 0

Tags: iri-legacy-api

I'm using `findTransactionObjects()` to receive all transaction objects for a given {address} which I used to **receive** IOTA.

In the data structure that gets returned, one of the Bundle Hashes can be found 47 times. {lastIndex} in these transactions is {3}. However, {currentIndex} is always {0}. In fact, there is no single occurrence where {currentIndex: > 0}.

What does this mean? My immediate questions:

- From the docs it is my understanding, {lastIndex} is the highest index for a transaction in the specific bundle. Is this correct?
- Why is there no single transaction with the {currentIndex > 0}?
- Does the fact that I see the Bundle Hash 47 times correspond to the number of times I might have reattached the transaction to get faster confirmation?

Please bear with me, if these are newbie questions but I want to get this right and support the community.

Answer (score 1):

You are querying transactions per **address**, the bundle indexes are only relevant if you query the transactions per **bundle hash**. Therefore, if you query the bundle by the bundle hash of your first search result, you will find the other transactions of the bundle (i. e. who **sent** the iota).

As a general convention, the first transaction in a bundle will be the (first) recipient, then followed by any other recipients (if spending to multiple addresses), then followed by the sender(s) and their signature transaction. Finally there may be a change transaction which sends the change back to a new address of the sender.

Therefore, if you only look at currentIndex=0, you will see *most* but not all spending transactions (i. e. you will miss those bundles that send to more than one address, and you will miss the change addresses).

The 47 times correspond to the number of attachments; the transactions should have different attachment timestamps, too.